# set value in java attribbute

Tags: java, setattribute

I am displaying certain application in the button , and each application on section show certain other option , but on choosing the final option .the previous one is being made null

For Example AppName = Test and then when it open , another variable DBName = test1, the value of AppName is null.

```
    </head>
        <form method="get">
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">

                                         <%



String s_userName = "admin";
String s_password = "password";
String S_olapSvrName ="";
String s_provider = "http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx"; 
final int FAILURE_CODE = 1;
int statusCode = 0;
IEssbase ess = null;
IEssOlapServer olapSvr = null;
IEssIterator ListCubeVar = null;

String VarAppDBName = null;


String VarAppName = request.getParameter("AppName");
//String VarAppDBName = request.getParameter("DBName");
                 //int NumDb1 = 0;
                 //int NumDb1 = olapSvr.getApplication(VarAppName).getCountCubes();
if((VarAppName == null)&&(VarAppDBName == null))
 {
VarAppName ="Sample";
VarAppDBName = "Basic"; 

 }

else if (VarAppName!=null)
{

 session.setAttribute(VarAppName,request.getParameter("AppName"));
  //session.setAttribute(VarAppDBName,request.getParameter("DBName"));

}

  S_olapSvrName ="xxx.xxx.xxx";
 ess = IEssbase.Home.create(IEssbase.JAPI_VERSION);
IEssDomain dom = ess.signOn(s_userName, s_password, false, null, s_provider);
olapSvr = (IEssOlapServer)dom.getOlapServer(S_olapSvrName);
olapSvr.connect();
ListCubeVar = olapSvr.getApplications();
IEssCube ListDBVar; 
 %>


        <% 

         int NumDb = olapSvr.getApplication(VarAppName).getCountCubes();
          session.setAttribute(VarAppName,request.getAttribute("AppName"));
            for(int k =0; k<NumDb;k++)  
        {%>    

        <input type ="submit" name ="DBName" value ="                  < <%=olapSvr.getApplication(VarAppName).getCubes().getAt(k)%>" size ="10"/> 

                <%} 
                                    // session.getValue("AppName");
                                     //session.getValue("DBName");
                                     session.setAttribute("DBName",request.getParameter("DBName"));
                                      %>                     
        <% int NumApp = ListCubeVar.getCount();
         for(int i = 0; i<NumApp;i++) {%>
        <input type="submit" name="AppName" value="<%=ListCubeVar.getAt(i)%></br>
        <%}
         %>
```

Comment: you didnt mention what is not working

Comment: This isn't Javascript. Is it Java or ASP.net?

Comment: sorry for that , yes when i am selecting the AppName, upon selecting the DBName , the AppName becomes null ,basically i want both AppName and DBName in the URl so that i can perform other thing.

Comment: this java script , OlapSVrname and other variable are being used from importing a jar of essbase , basically this is to connect with the essbase , another application .

Comment: Java !== JavaScript https://www.flickr.com/photos/schrader/3779250024/